# QGIS: an offset line symbol works fine in layout but not in exported image

Tags: qgis, symbology, offset

[image][image]In QGIS (multiple versions), I have 2 overlapping lines. For clarity i use offset on one of them in the symbol properties. This looks fine in layout manager, the lines are next to each other. When i export as image, the two lines are on top of each other again, as if it doesn't use the offset value anymore.

Comment: Pics or it didn't happen aka please provide screenshots illustrating the disparities, as well as the exact symbology. Thank you.

Comment: added a pic but feels like it behaves the other way around now.. zoomed in, offset disappears.. zoomed out offset line shows

Comment: It looks like the main issue is with the line width. The exported width seems much bigger than the layout line width (which could explain why an offset of 1mm is not enough anymore)

Comment: yea i am by no means an expert with this. Just using it to make some ok looking maps for a presentation (many of them) . I don't know exactly how to make a line width that scales kind of nicely with different zoom-levels. Maybe there is an option for linewidth that scales with the zoom-level? I just use the mm property because it is the default..

Comment: thanks for thinking with me btw